# What is wlan0 called on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, console

I need to use some console admin tools on Windows 7 and I am used to Linux/Unix. So, in Linux I would type something like this

```
command -param1 -param2 wlan0
```

and the `command` would do something on wireless interface.

What is the name for wifi interface on windows 7? What would such command look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the netsh command (start with netsh /? and have a look at this url : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725935%28v=ws.10%29 ).
for wifi the context is wlan as in : netsh wlan show all

Comment: Does this mean than `wlan0` in linux is the same as `wlan` on windows?

Comment: no, wlan is a category, a windows adapter is named something like : " Connexion réseau sans fil". use : netsh wlan show interfaces to get the names of the network cards. you can rename them btw.

Comment: notice netsh behaves like a shell : type "netsh" <CR> then type wlan <CR> then type help <CR>

Comment: Also, since it appears the OP asks for only the name, I would suggest running `netsh wlan show interfaces` (or more specifically `netsh wlan show interfaces | findstr Name`)